# Проверить упорядоченность списка STL

Tags: c++, список

Для ответа на вопрос задачи надо определить, отсортирована последовательность по возрастанию или в ней есть нарушения порядка. Я плохо знаю C++ и понятнее было бы самому написать список, но удобнее будет взять готовую абстракцию. Что я делаю не так при использовании итераторов? На последнем шаге итератор показывает в самое начало списка, и из-за этого результат неверный.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    std::list<int> balls;
    int n, ball, curr;
    bool cheater;

    std::cin >> n;

    while(!std::cin.eof()){
        std::cin >> ball;
        balls.push_back(ball);
    }

    cheater = false;
    std::list<int>::iterator it = balls.begin();
    while(it != balls.end()){
        std::cout << *it << " ";
        curr = *it;
        if(curr >= *(++it)) cheater = true;
        std::cout << "curr = " << curr << ", it = " << *it << std::endl;
        curr = *it;
        //it++;
    }
```

https://ideone.com/GhVr70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы определить, отсортирована ли последовательность, достаточно использовать стандартный алгоритм `std::is_sorted`, определенный в заголовке `<algorithm>`.

Например,

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

bool cheater = std::is_sorted( balls.begin(), balls.end() );
```

Что касается вашего кода, то данное предложение

```
    if(curr >= *(++it)) cheater = true;
```

имеет неопределенное поведение, когда `it` указывает на последний элемент.

Имейте в виду, что данный цикл

```
while(!std::cin.eof()){
    std::cin >> ball;
    balls.push_back(ball);
}
```

некорректен.

Правильно будет записать

```
while(std::cin >> ball){
    balls.push_back(ball);
}
```

Иначе вы можете записать в список элемент, который не вводили.

Comment: "Правильно будет записать" Странно, а я в какой-то задаче пытался сделать цикл в сишном стиле, когда в качестве условия используется результат выражения присваивания, но тот код не скомпилировался. Тоже использовал std::cin в условии. Когда элементы закончились, cin возвращает 0?

Comment: @typemoon Когда элементы закончатся, то он использует оператор преобразования в bool, и возвращает false.

Comment: А почему эта программа дает неверный результат? Ведь список упорядочен. Ответ стал неверным после того, как я изменил цикл заполнения списка. https://ideone.com/HEvzDr

Comment: @typemoon Программа работает правильно. Ваш список не отсортирован по возрастанию.